# letsencrypt free SSL instaltion on cpanel server

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, lets-encrypt

**[letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) is free new Certificate Authority**

Now issues has been solved, i am editing this question because if someone is also facing same issues than please check **cPanel's official plugin** at:

Ref: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/The+Let%27s+Encrypt+Plugin

That i am want to install on cPanel's server domain.

I have followed there [How It Works](https://letsencrypt.org/howitworks/)

```
$ git clone https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt
$ cd letsencrypt
$ ./letsencrypt-auto --help
```

But it is not working

**My console log**

```
root@host5 [~/letsencrypt]# ./letsencrypt-auto certonly --standalone -d softechdevelop.com -d www.softechdevelop.com
Bootstrapping dependencies for RedHat-based OSes...
yum is /usr/bin/yum
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.chpc.utah.edu
 * extras: mirror.tocici.com
 * updates: mirrors.usc.edu
Package python-2.6.6-64.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package python-devel-2.6.6-64.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
No package python-virtualenv available.
Nothing to do
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.chpc.utah.edu
 * extras: mirror.tocici.com
 * updates: mirrors.usc.edu
Package git-1.7.1-3.el6_4.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package gcc-4.4.7-16.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package dialog-1.1-9.20080819.1.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package augeas-libs-1.0.0-10.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package openssl-devel-1.0.1e-42.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libffi-devel-3.0.5-3.2.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package redhat-rpm-config-9.0.3-44.el6.centos.noarch already installed and latest version
Package ca-certificates-2015.2.4-65.0.1.el6_6.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
WARNING: Python 2.6 support is very experimental at present...
if you would like to work on improving it, please ensure you have backups
and then run this script again with the --debug flag!
root@host5 [~/letsencrypt]# ./letsencrypt-auto
Bootstrapping dependencies for RedHat-based OSes...
yum is /usr/bin/yum
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.chpc.utah.edu
 * extras: mirror.ancl.hawaii.edu
 * updates: mirrors.usc.edu
Package python-2.6.6-64.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package python-devel-2.6.6-64.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
No package python-virtualenv available.
Nothing to do
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.chpc.utah.edu
 * extras: mirror.tocici.com
 * updates: mirrors.usc.edu
Package git-1.7.1-3.el6_4.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package gcc-4.4.7-16.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package dialog-1.1-9.20080819.1.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package augeas-libs-1.0.0-10.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package openssl-devel-1.0.1e-42.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package libffi-devel-3.0.5-3.2.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package redhat-rpm-config-9.0.3-44.el6.centos.noarch already installed and latest version
Package ca-certificates-2015.2.4-65.0.1.el6_6.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
WARNING: Python 2.6 support is very experimental at present...
if you would like to work on improving it, please ensure you have backups
and then run this script again with the --debug flag!
```

If any one has knowledge of SSL installation with apache than your suggestion will be very helpful for me and all other website owners of the whole world.

Comment: I have a CentOS 6.7 system without cPanel and the process works fine. My guess is that you are not up-to-date and/or the odd configuration that cPanel uses is causing you this issue. The [cPanel support site](https://features.cpanel.net/topic/provide-support-for-lets-encrypt-automated-certificate-management-ssl) actually has information that is relevant too. Questions involving cPanel (and other panel) systems are not topical here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from your logs:

- you are using python 2.6 which they feel is dodgy enough to label it `very experimental`
- you are missing the `python-virtualenv` package, possibly because it is not available for your distribution

I'm guessing you are on RHEL6/centos6 and so your python 2.7 packages are named `python27*` and the [lets-encrypt](/questions/tagged/lets-encrypt) scripts are not smart enough to figure that out yet.